# How can a Windows container in Docker Desktop access a container in Minikube?

Tags: docker, networking, minikube

I have 2 applications that i need to run locally... they would work best if together in the same cluster, the problem is:

- one is suited for Linux containers, so i'm hosting it on Minikube
- the other is suited for Windows containers - which Minikube does not work - so i'm hosting it on Docker Desktop

These applications need to talk with each other. I configured a NGINX server on the host to act as a reverse proxy to redirect the requests.

My problem is that inside the Windows container (Docker desktop) i need to access an URL which is on the host machine (pointing to Minikube), but it's not reachable from inside the container.

I tried `network_mode: host` but it doesn't work for Windows. How can i access the host network in Windows containers?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work so i deployed everything in Docker Desktop.

Deploy the linux containers, then switch to windows containers and deploy it. I had to edit the hosts file inside the container to match my host IP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).